# Implement IEquatable on different types

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class such that:

```
 public class Foo : IEquatable<Bar>, IComparable{

 [DataMember]
 public Bar bar;

 public override bool Equals(object obj){
     //Check if not hte right object, return false;
     return this.bar == obj as Bar;
 }
 public bool Equals(Bar other){
    if(this.bar == other){
        return this.bar == other;
    }
 }
}
```

I want to be able to have a list of Foo's, which contain bars, and use the Contains() method to check to see if Bar bar is inside the list of Foos.  So far, I've had no luck, and from what i've read you can only compare types with IEquatable if they have the same parent that defines IEquatable or if they are the same type.

Any one know if you can implement

```
List<Foo> foos.Contains(Bar bar) ?
```

Also, I'd like to have a list of Bars, and be able to remove any that are contained in a list of Foos, such that;

```
 List<Bar> bars = bars.Where( r => (List<Foo>) !foos.Contains(r)).ToList();  \
```

This is the most important thing I need, and looks really clean.  Of course, I could just do these comparison in a for each loop, but I want to avoid that if possible and maybe not pay an n*m penalty.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion this code looks really weird:

```
foos.Contains(bar)
```

What do you think about:

```
foos.Any(f => f.Bar == bar)
```

Code after you update - I assume you have collection of `bars` and you want to exclude all Bars that are referenced by Foos in `foos` collection:

```
bars.Except(foos.Select(f => f.Bar))
```

Comment: I like it, but lets say I've got a list of Bars, and I want to keep in finalBars only the unique entries.  Would this work?  finalBars => foos.any(f => f.Bar.barid != finalBars.any(r => r.barid))?

Comment: @Magn3s1um I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want unique bars or unique foos? Maybe you should update your question and give more detailed description.

Comment: @Magn3s1um - it feels like you trying to implement very slow version of [Enumerable.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) that takes comparer... Check out my answer for possible comparer that may help you there.

Comment: @Magn3s1um check my updated answer - do you want something like this?

Comment: That's perfect actually, but can you go one further, as in: bars.Except(where bars.Property is not in foos.Bars.Property)?

Comment: @Magn3s1um if you have collection of foosOther you may write foosOther.Select(f => f.Bar) instead of bars; however, it's hard to give you an answer if you don't state what do you have in beginning and what do you want achieve

Comment: thanks, I can do it like this: finalbars.where(r => m_SavedGadgets.Any(f => f.Bar.Property != r.Property)).  Thanks for the help

Comment: @Magn3s1um - just be careful if you have non-trival number of items - `Where(...Any...)` is `O(n^2)` or `O(n*m)` (n items in foos, m items in SavedGadgets) where `Distinct` is `O(n)` or `O(n + m)`

Answer (score 1):

Empi's answer with `foo.Any(f => f.Bar == bar)` looks very clean to me, but if you want to stick with comparison - use the other override of [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) and create custom "CompareFooByBar" comparer (also you still need to pass `Foo` as search term, but you can use totally fake one).

```
class CompareFooByBar : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        return x.Bar == y.Bar;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo x)
    {
        return  x.Bar.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
foos.Contains(new Foo{Bar = bar}, new CompareFooByBar())
```

One more option is to completely cheat and have comparer that simply compares to fixed value (but it would rely on internal implementation of `Contains` to call `Equals` with particular order of arguments and make `Equals` non-symmetric):

```
class CompareFooToBar : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
{
    Bar bar;
    public CompareFooToBar(Bar bar) { this.bar = bar;}

    public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        // hack - ignore y completely, assuming Contains pass element as x
        return x.Bar == bar; 
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Foo x) 
    {
        return  0;
    }
}

foos.Contains(null, new CompareFooToBar(bar))
```